# how to fire mouseleave when the mouse leaves 2 divs using jquery

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

i have 2 divs next to each other i want mouseleave to fire when the mouse leaves the 2 divs not when it leaves one of them.

how can i do that using jquery?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could surround the two divs with another div and catch the mouseleave on that.

Comment: This is probably the best way because it doesn't matter if there's a gutter space between them.